# Plotting the hyperplane of LDA (ClassificationDiscriminant)

Tags: matlab, classification

I am trying to compare various classifiers on my data, such as LDA and SVM etc, by visually investigate the separation hyperplane.

Currently I am using ClassificationDiscriminant as the LDA classifier, unlike SVM can draw the hyperplane on the graph, I could not find a way to plot the hyperplane of the LDA classifier.

The following script is how I produce a sample data and get it been classified using ClassificationDiscriminant:

```
%% Data & Label
X = [randn(100,2); randn(150,2) + 1.5];
Y = [zeros(100,1); ones(150,1)];
%% Plot
gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),Y);
%% Train LDA Classifier
C = ClassificationDiscriminant.fit(X,Y);
```

Can anyone please help me to plot the hyperplane of separation from `C`? Any suggestion would be great help.

Furthermore, the sample above is in 2D, however, I'm also interested in plotting them in 3D (i.e. sample data `X` has three columns). It would be more great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the example in Matlab's `classify()` documentation:

```
Class1 = 1;
Class2 = 2;
K = C.Coeffs(Class1,Class2).Const;
L = C.Coeffs(Class1,Class2).Linear;
f = @(x,y) K + [x y]*L;

hold on;
ezplot(f, [min(X(:,1)) max(X(:,1)) min(X(:,2)) max(X(:,2))]);
```

Note that the above example plots the pairwise boundary between two classes in 2 dimensional space.  If you have additional classes, you will have to modify `Class1` and `Class2` appropriately.  I'm sure with some additional work you can find an extension of this function to N dimensional space.

Comment: Many thanks Ryan.
As there are some difference between `classify` and `ClassificationDiscriminant` (seen in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944812/difference-between-matlabs-classify-and-classificationdiscriminant)), I am more interested in stick with the latter classifier to keep integrity with my previous work. Any further suggestion about finding hyperplane from this function?

Comment: Did you *try* the code yet? Even though I based it off `classify` I rewrote it to work with `ClassificationDiscriminant`.  Literally all you have to do is copy and paste and run it following your initial code snippet.